# How to use if else statment in javascript with multiple drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, html

*I am trying to print select in multiple drop-down list, but prints only two words(CHENNAI AND IOS-XE , BANGALORE AND IOS-XR) could not print the remaining words
Can anyone help me fix this?*

**Required Output :**

if i select CHENNAI+IOS-XE   ---> output : CHENNAI AND IOS-XE

else if   BANGALORE+IOS-XR ---> output : BANGALORE AND IOS-XR

else if   CHENNAI+IOS-XR   ---> output : CHENNAI AND IOS-XR

else if   BANGALORE+IOS-XE ---> output : BANGALORE AND IOS-XE

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>SELECT THE REGION </p>
  <select id="choose">
    <option value="a1">CHENNAI</option>
    <option value="b1">BANGALORE</option>
  </select></p>
  
  <p>SELECT THE ROUTER TYPE </p>
  <select id="choose1">
    <option value="a2">IOS-XE</option>
    <option value="b2">IOS-XR</option>
  </select></p>
  
  <button onclick="button()">CLICK</button>

  <script>
    function button() {
      var x = document.getElementById("choose").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("choose1").value;
      if (x == 'a1' || y == 'a2' ) {
        document.write("CHENNAI AND IOS-XE");
      }
      else if (x == 'b1' || y == 'b2'){
        document.write("BANGALORE AND IOS-XR");
      }
      else if (x == 'a1' || y == 'b2'){
        document.write("CHENNAI AND IOS-XR");
      }   
      else if (x == 'b1' || y == 'a2'){
        document.write("BANGALORE AND IOS-XE");
      }       
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` statement cannot contain a condition check.

You need to change the logic to the following:

```js
if (x == 'a1') {
  document.write("A SELECTED");
}
else if (x == 'b1'){
//   ^  added this :)
  document.write("B SELECTED");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`else` shouldn't have any conditions in it, if you want to use a condition for it you should use `else if`:

```
else if ( x == 'b1' ) {
    // Your statement
}
```

or you can use a general `else` for all other cases:

```
else {
    // Your statement
}
```